# Packages are missing when Xamarin commit-push to github

Tags: git, github, package, nuget-package

i have cloned a repository from GitHub then run it. Works fine!
Then i had to commit-push this working project to a new repository. When i committed to a new repository, packages folder is missing (i have my own framework in packages folder). Rest of the documents , committed successfully.

why might cause this issue ?

Comment: check your .gitignore file

Comment: #Nuget Packages

Comment: #Nuget Packages - *.nupkg  #The packages folder can be ignored because of Package Restore **/[Pp]ackages/* #except build, which is used  as an MSBuild target.  !**/[Pp]ackages/build/   # Uncomment if necessary however generally it will be regenerated when needed   #!**/[Pp]ackages/repositories.config #Nuget v3'.s project.json files produces more ignorable files  *.nuget.props    *.nuget.targets